# Using the same index to map two arrays in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to display a table in React. The first column is all the courses taught by the prof, and the second column is at most three comments associated with that course. Data for all the courses are stored at

```
this.state.courses
```

All the comments are nested array mapping to the course order. Access comments for the first course is

```
this.state.comments[0]
```

My code for now did not work, but this is my attempt

```
                    <Table striped bordered hover>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{`Courses Taught By ${this.state.professorname}`}</th>
                                <th>{`Comments on Course`}</th>
                                <th>{`Comments on Prof`}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                {this.state.courses.map((course, i) => (
                                    <td key={i}>
                                        <Link to={`/${this.state.id}/${course._id}`}>{course.name}</Link>
                                    </td>
                                ))}
                                {this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => {
                                    <td key={j}>
                                        <p>{this.state.comments[i][j]}</p>
                                    </td>
                                })}
                            </tr> 
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
```

I could really the help for this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second loop is out of the scope of the first one - it does not have access to `i`.

You should move the second `map` inside the first one, to be able to access it.

```
<tr>
    {this.state.courses.map((course, i) => (
       <>
          <td key={course._id}>
             <Link to={`/${this.state.id}/${course._id}`}>{course.name}</Link>
          </td>
          {this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => (
             <td key={j}>
                <p>{this.state.comments[i][j]}</p>
             </td>
          ))}
      </>
    ))}                                   
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi @kind user, thank you so much for the response. However, I changed to the code you suggested. This is the error message: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression for ```<td key={j}>```

Comment: @SkipperLin Oh, of course - you had also a syntax error - just replace `{` with `(` ==> `{this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => (`

Comment: Hi @kind user, that makes sense. Understood. One follow up question: technically I hope the data for each array is displayed in a column; however, for now the data for the ```this.state.courses``` is displayed in a row. Many thanks.

Comment: @SkipperLin Hmm, that problem actually worths a new question:) because you need to restructure your table (depends on your needs). You should probably try to replace td with tr

Comment: for sure. I will try that! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SkipperLin My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Two problem I can see in your code.

First  `i` from first loop is not available in second loop(out of scope).

Second you are not returning anything in second map functions.

```
<tr>
{this.state.courses.map((course, i) => (
   <>
      <td key={course._id}>
         <Link to={`/${this.state.id}/${course._id}`}>{course.name}</Link>
      </td>
      {this.state.comments[i].map((comment, j) => {
  return (
         <td key={j}>
            <p>{this.state.comments[i][j]}</p>
         </td>
      )
   })}
  </>
))}                                   
</tr>
```